# Optimization of Memory while reading a large excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, memory, recursive-query

I do have an excel file of which i developed a way of reading all the contents in sheet 1 and populates it into a listview, basically the sheet has data in cells A-D. but the number is 120,000. when i run the code, it does read these files , takes time but during the process, any action on the form like minimizing or clicking on the form anywhere freezes the program and causes it to crash. how can i improve on performance like any good program does. here is my code below.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = new 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
         // prepare open file dialog to only search for excel files (had 
        //  trouble setting this in design view)

         openFileDialog1.FileName = "*.xlsx";
         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             // Here is the call to Open a Workbook in Excel 
            // It uses most of the default values (except for the read-only 
           // which we set to true)

                Workbook theWorkbook =   
                ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, 0, true, 
                5,"", "", true,  XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 
                0, true);


            // get the collection of sheets in the workbook

               Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

            // get the first and only worksheet from the collection of 
           //  worksheets

            Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);

            // loop through 10 rows of the spreadsheet and place each row in 
            // the list view

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "J" + 
                i.ToString());
                System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
                string[] strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(strArray));
            }
        }

    }


       string[] ConvertToStringArray(System.Array values)
           {
        // create a new string array

        string[] theArray = new string[values.Length];

         // loop through the 2-D System.Array and populate the 1-D String 
        // Array

        for (int i = 1; i <= values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (values.GetValue(1, i) == null)
                theArray[i - 1] = "";
            else
                theArray[i - 1] = (string)values.GetValue(1, i).ToString();
        }
        return theArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of interop i would recommend using OpenXML (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)
- And use something like BackgroundWorker to read the file in the background (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)